# Recreating jQuery's $.ajax().done()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create my own "basic" javascript framework, I want it to work in somewhat similar ways to `jQuery` and I've fallen in love with method chaining over instead of callbacks. However, implementing this is tough for me as a junior javascripter.

I have now created my own `ajax` "class" but I can't seem to figure out how to recreate the `.done()` jQuery uses.

I want this syntax to work in order to get rid of my callback hell;

`ajax(url, type, data).success(function(response){});`

However, this results in `response` being `false`. Obviously, because it's being called before my ajax call is even done.

I've tried inserting a promise but that only got me lots of syntax errors or vague errors like `uncaught (in promise) OK`.

This is what my code currently looks like;

```
var ajax = function(url, method, data) {
  if(!(this instanceof ajax))
  {
    return new ajax(url, method, data);
  }
  var ajaxObj = this;
  var prom    = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ajaxObj.xhttp     = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxObj.url       = url;
    ajaxObj.data      = data;
    ajaxObj.urlParams = '';
    ajaxObj.response  = false;
    ajaxObj.get();
    ajaxObj.xhttp.send();
    ajaxObj.xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
      {
        resolve(this.responseText);
      }
      else
      {
        reject(this.statusText);
      }
    };

  });

  return prom;
};

ajax.prototype.get = function() {
  var urlParams = serialize(this.data);
  this.xhttp.open("GET", this.url + urlParams);
  return this;
};

ajax.prototype.success = function(callBack) {
  callBack(this.response);
};

      //My function call;
  ajax('url', 'GET', {
    'Testval': 'testvalue',
    'field': 'value'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log("Response is:" + response);
  }).catch(function(response){});
```

-- My serialize function for those wondering:

```
var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
  var str = [], p;
  for(p in obj)
  {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p))
    {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
      str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
              serialize(v, k) :
              encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return '?' + str.join("&");
};
```

-- **NOTE:**

I want to achieve being able to call my ajax function like so:

```
ajax(url, type, data).success(function(response){
  //The responseData has already been handled by the success function before the callback.
  //On success
}).error(function(error){
  // On error
});
```

-- This does **NOT** have to be through promises. It can be through any way possible, I just do not know any.

Comment: What is the expected result of `this[strType]()`?

Comment: It calls an extended function (in this case `ajax.prototype.get()`) -- so it sets the `xhttp.open();`

Comment: When the function is called `serialize` is not defined

Comment: `serialize()` is a custom function so I left it out to minimise the codeblock. I'll add it for you.

Comment: The expected result is returned here. How do you execute `success`?

Comment: I happen to have just added an answer to that question. I would like it to work from chaining. `ajax().success();`

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when there are numerous other request libraries around already that have been heavily used and debugged across numerous browsers/environments

Comment: @charlietfl for very specific needs and minimising bloat. It's all part of a bigger picture with set returns for these ajax calls. I only need a few very simple functions with very few options to make it work, but need to do things in a specific way to minimise duplicate code. (mostly checks)

Comment: @Babydead _"and minimising bloat"_ , _"a few very simple functions"_ ? That is not the gist of the original Question whatsoever. Use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` without _creating_ more code.

Comment: @guest271314 I have like 14k ajax calls, which have response-checking statements after every call. You're trying to tell me that building a few functions to remove all of this clutter and take away some bytes is creating more code? With your responses I feel you're being really condescending towards me and are just commenting make me seem stupid or something.

Comment: @Babydead _"I want to simply chain my success function on my ajax function instead of using a callback."_ That is what the deleted Answer achieves, by still using the "callback" function within a pattern using `Promise`. The names of the functions are not important. The number of the function calls increased by 10 fold within the span of several comments _"I have about 1420 different ajax calls"_ and _" I have like 14k ajax calls"_ though that is wholly irrelevant to the original Question - and in fact also to what you are trying to achieve. Am not here to engage in social niceties.

Comment: @Babydead And no, did not call you out of your name nor have such concepts at all. There is no condescending. We are all equal in potential. This is direct communication. There are people on this board who will engage you and try to help as best they can. You will get help and surely resolve your inquiry with continued effort on your behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would do it with promises. In that case `ajax` would *return* that promise, and would therefore not be a constructor. The chained method is called `then`.

```js
var ajax = function(url, method, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            strType = method.toLowerCase(),
            methods = {
                get: function() {
                    var urlParams = serialize(data);
                    xhttp.open("GET", url + urlParams);
                }
            };
        methods[strType]();
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState !== 4) return;
            resolve(this.status == 200 ? this.responseText : this.statusText);
        };
        xhttp.onerror = xhttp.onabort = reject;
    });
};

//My function call;
ajax('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=200', 'GET', {
    'Testval': 'testvalue',
    'field': 'value'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log("Response is:" + response);
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("There was an error or the request was aborted.");
});

function serialize(obj, prefix) {
    var str = [], p;
    for(p in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
            str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
                serialize(v, k) :
                encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
    }
    return '?' + str.join("&");
};
```

If you prefer the name `success` then do:

```
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // ...etc
    });
    promise.success = promise.then;
    promise.error = promise.catch;
    return promise;
```

:-)  Of course, now you have a promise object with non-standard method names, which is not really something that would be considered best practice. Better stick with standard promises.

Comment: Ahh yes, I know of this method (though I don't understand it fully yet). I take issue with this method, however. I do not want to call `then()`. I want to be able to stack `.success()`, `.error()` etc. I don't want my entire scripts to be full of thens and catches. :(

Comment: @Babydead Then you would need to convert `success` to `.then()`. You cannot expect asynchronous code to run synchronously

Comment: Do you really have a problem with the names `then` and `catch` as opposed to `success` and `error`!? Note that also jQuery is now supporting `then` and `catch` as with the Promises/A+ spec it became the standard way of chaining asynchronous method callbacks.

Comment: @trincot that is not what it is about. It's about differentiating the results. I have about 1420 different ajax calls, all differentiating through the response in the callback which of 6 different resulttypes it is. I want to be able to do the if-statement beforehand to remove tons of duplicate code...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Why would you have duplicate code? Just create one function you'd like to call when there is success, and pass that. I have no idea which `if` statement you are referring to.

Comment: @Babydead How is your last comment related  to the original Question _"Recreating jQuery's $.ajax().done()"_ ? Note that `jQuery.deferred.done` is not compatible with `Promise.prototype.then`

Comment: @guest271314 I get th feeling you do not understand what I want to achieve. I want to simply chain my success function on my ajax function instead of using a callback. I do not know how to and do not know how jquery does it nor do I understand how Promise works (which seems to be quite new). This is why I'm here, asking for help. If I knew all these things, I wouldn't be in need of help.

Comment: @trincot you may be right about that, actually. If that promise is how I can use understandable names like "success" and "error" instead of then and catch, I will give it a shot. I'm going to try it right now!

Comment: As mentioned, I am unfamiliar with promise() so I did not understand the syntax very well. I was getting back both the reject and resolve but I understand it better now. Thank you =)

Comment: Hello,

I'm afraid I have another question... I would like to be able to handle the data before the return. So, with my chained function call (Whether it's then or success or whatever doesn't really matter) I would already have like to function to have manipulated the data. (I generally catch specific responses that aren't errors per say). How would I go about this and still be able to chain in my function call? Otherwise I'll have the same if statements/function call within every `.then()` and that feels wrong haha.

Comment: Sure, you can chain a `.then` to the `new Promise( ..... )` inside the `ajax` function. Make sure that `then` callback returns the (maybe modified) response. If you have trouble making it work, then please ask a new question about the specific problem.

Comment: @trincot You are right. I'm sorry, it was a pretty stupid question. I can obviously call for the function handling the data within the promise and the `then()`. will have the manipulated data. For some reason, logical thinking gets hard when you don't fully understand the syntax yet :p... My bad. Stupid question